# problem in boolean expression with condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to set new variables 'not_good', 'good' and 'very good' based on the column quality.
So, each line in the data set, I will only have '1' in one of those and two '0' in the two remaining variables.
I used the code above,

```
for i in range(1599):
if (data.quality[i] == 3) or (data.quality[i] == 4):
    data.not_good = 1
if (data.quality[i] == 5) or (data.quality[i] == 6):
    data.good = 1
if (data.quality[i] == 7) or (data.quality[i] == 8):
    data.very_good =1
```

the cell run perfectly but I find that all the variables I added are equal to 1 for all Lines.

Comment: Assuming the "... good" variables are also columns you must set them for the particular row by appending "[i]".

Comment: Can you share some example data? This isn't very clear.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to use 0 and 1, a boolean is far more appropriate. It might also be a good idea to have a single column, of categorical data type, which would contain one of the three quality levels.

Answer (score 0):

You have one object data. 
That data object has 4 variables:

```
not_good : int
good : int
very_good : int
quality : int[] # int array
```

as long as one of the data is not_good, good or very_good you have a one everywhere. 
You can solve it when you choose the type not as int but as int[] then the code would look like this:

```
data_length = 1599

data.not_good = [0]*data_length
data.good = [0]*data_length
data.very_good = [0]*data_length

for i in range(data_length):
if (data.quality[i] == 3) or (data.quality[i] == 4):
    data.not_good[i] = 1
if (data.quality[i] == 5) or (data.quality[i] == 6):
    data.good[i] = 1
if (data.quality[i] == 7) or (data.quality[i] == 8):
    data.very_good[i] =1
```

Comment: just the cell before i defined new variables as int

Comment: a = ['not_good', 'good', 'very_good'] 
for i in range(3):
    data[a[i]] = np.nan

Comment: and 'quality' is int64 type

Comment: @TrikiSadok it doesn't really matter if it is int64 or something else. The point is that one is a list/array the other is not. 
And the initialization proves what I wrote? I'm not sure what you want to tell me with that?

Answer (score 0):

- Explicit loops should be avoided as much as possible when working with Pandas.
- Instead of 0 or 1, it's better to just use a boolean.
- Rather than having three columns, one for each quality level, why not use a single categorical column? You can read more about categorical data in Pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).